# Sorting multi-type string ArrayList in Java based on Integers

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a data Set like this:

```
1,JOHN,1934
2,TERENCE,1914
3,JOHN,1964
4,JOHN,1904
5,JOHN,1924
6,JOHN,1954
7,JOHN,1944
8,JOHN,1984
9,JOHN,1974
10,JOHN,1994
```

Which I've loaded in ArrayList of `String[]` from Text file like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<>();
String fileLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String dataPath = fileLocation + File.separator + "boys-names.txt";
try {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataPath))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            records.add(values);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I wanted to sort data set in increasing **year** like this:

```
4,JOHN,1904
2,TERENCE,1914
5,JOHN,1924
1,JOHN,1934
7,JOHN,1944
6,JOHN,1954
3,JOHN,1964
9,JOHN,1974
8,JOHN,1984
10,JOHN,1994
```

**Problem:** The built-in sorting method `Collections.sort(list);` of ArrayList only works on single type of data. But, in my case I have string with multi-type (string-integer) and sorting should base in *Integers*. So, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: The proper way to do this would be not using string arrays, but rather parsing each line into a proper object, that has ID, name and year, and making a list of that. You can then sort using `Comparator`.

Comment: let me see this

Comment: Is your String array length of each list is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using java-8 lambda expression, write custom `Comparator` that compares `Integer` values and use `Integer.valueOf` for converting `String` to `Integer`

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

String[] ar1 = {"1","JOHN","1934"};
String[] ar2 = {"2","TERENCE","1914"};

list.add(ar1);
list.add(ar2);

list.sort((c1,c2)->Integer.valueOf(c1[2]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(c2[2])));

list.forEach(i->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i)));
```

**Output**

```
[2, TERENCE, 1914]
[1, JOHN, 1934]
```

Comment: what's `Arrays.toString(i)` ? I wanted your solution not model class.

Comment: It is to print `Array` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array @5377037

Answer (score 5):

Consider defining a model class for your data - let's call it `MyData` :

```
public class MyData {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Year year;

    //getters setters constructor
}
```

If the last integer value represents a year, why not use [`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) directly?
And then you could sort this list using [`List::sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method and passing a comparator :

```
Comparator<MyData> comparator = Comparator.comparing(MyData::getYear);

myDataList.sort(comparator);
```

Comment: This seems to be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<>();
    records.add(new String[] {"1", "John", "1934"});
    records.add(new String[] {"2", "Terence", "1914"});

        Collections.sort(
            records,
            (o1, o2) -> {
              Integer year_o1 = Integer.parseInt(o1[2]);
              Integer year_o2 = Integer.parseInt(o2[2]);
              if (year_o1 < year_o2) {
                return -1;
              } else if (year_o1 > year_o2) {
                return 1;
              } else {
                return 0;
              }
            });
      }
```

Comment: Why write that long `if` statement when there is an `Integer.compare` method?

Comment: Oh you are right, that would drastically reduce the verbosity of the above method. Did not hit me.